# How do I compute this integral of the following $2$ form in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Tags: integration, analysis, differential-forms, parametrization, submanifold

I have the following problem:

> let M be the unit sphere and $\omega=x~dy\wedge dz+y~dz\wedge dx+z~dx\wedge dy$ be our $2$-Form. we want to compute $$\int_M \omega$$

In the lecture we did the following. Take the parametrisation $\phi(\theta,\rho)=(\cos\theta\sin\rho,\sin\theta\sin\rho,\cos\rho)$ where $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ and $\rho \in [0,\pi]$. We know that this parametrisation is an orientable chart. Till this point everything is clear to me. But then we wrote that for this parametrisation the following point $$\{y=0,x>0\}$$ are missing, but since this set has measure zero one can "ignore" this fact.

And that's the thing I don't understand. First of all I don't get where I can see that exaclty this points are missing, and therefore I also can't see why this is a nullset.

Could someone explain this to me because the rest (computations) are clear afterwards.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure which kind of definitions you use, but in order for this to be a parametrization and hence the inverse to be a chart you need the domain to be a open set and you want your parametrization to be injective on this set. So you want $\theta\in (0,2\pi)$ and $\rho \in (0,\pi)$.

Comment: but has this something to do with this points that are missing?

Comment: Yes, now you can't reach points which are of the form $\phi(0,\rho)=(\cos(0)\sin(\rho),\sin(0)\sin(\rho),\cos\rho)$, which I think is meant with your notation: $\{y=0,x>0\}$. You should convince yourself that this set is only half a equator on the sphere and hence a zero set.

Comment: Sorry so did I understood this correctly? By definition of a chart, the domain has to be open, thus instead of $[0,2\pi]$ and $[0,\pi]$ we take $(0,2\pi)$ and $(0,\pi)$. But then somehow a vertical quarter quator line is missing, so I mean the curve from $(1,0,0)$ to $(0,0,1)$ on the boundary of the sphere is missing. But since we are in $\Bbb{R}^3$ we have the three dimensional lebesgue measure $\lambda_3$ but the curve is only one dimensional so it has measure zero with respect to $\lambda_3$. is this correct so?

Comment: Almost. The piece that is missing is a curve on an equator from $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,0,-1)$. We are on the sphere, which has a two-dimensional measure and hence the curve has measure zero on it. But essentially thats it.

Comment: ah yes I see thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a write-up of the comments on the question:

It depends on the definitions you are using, but in order to have a parametrization that is an inverse of a chart you need the domain to be an open set. So you want $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ and $\rho \in (0,\pi)$. But with this open set you cannot reach points of the form

$$\phi(0,\rho)=(\cos(0)\sin(\rho),\sin(0)\sin(\rho),\cos(\rho)).$$

If you inspect those points you find that this is a curve on an equator from $(0,0,1)$ to $(0,0,-1)$. Since the sphere is two dimensional this gives a set of measure zero.